# Configuring Sendmail to report successful deliveries

Tags: sendmail, email-bounces, report, email

I now have Sendmail report the fail deliveries by bouncing back to a bounce mailbox. E.g. failure to reach joe@example.com would bounce back to bounce+joe=example.com@mysite.com.

I was wondering if is possible to configure Sendmail to report successful deliveries in a similar manner.

Can I make it bounce to a similar address and say that email WAS delivered to joe@example.com ?
Or should I just rely on the maillog file to analyze successful deliveries?

I am not sure what is a good practice to keep an eye on successful deliveries.

Edit: I am sending many emails to around 200 000 registered and confirmed members on around 4 different sites, recently I seen some dedicated email delivery services like Mandrill or SendGrid, I see Mandrill has a list of all recent messages with status next to it (delivered or bounced), I was wondering how are they tracking the delivers.

Comment: RFC 3461 (as updated) deals with DSN.

Comment: What do you use to send/compose the messages?

Comment: I am sending them by PHP scripts, loading one by one from a queue database. @lain I will look at RFC 3461 , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the fact that you didn't get a failure bounce-back convenient enough?

You should be able to look to logs in the case where you need to verify a particular email and this seems much more effective then sending an email for each successful delivery.

Good practice will depend on your use case and what you're hoping to achieve, how big you are, how many emails you churn through, company policies etc but you want to be careful of not going to far and firing off emails for the sake of it.

Comment: I am sending many emails to around 200 000 registered and confirmed members on around 4 different sites, recently I seen some dedicated email delivery services like Mandrill or SendGrid, I see Mandrill has a list of all recent messages with status next to it (delivered or bounced), I was wondering how are they tracking the delivers.

Comment: Amazon also has a mail service.